# how do I calculate heightForRowAtIndexPath when the cell is not even constructed yet?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

Question - How does one best calculate the height for a row in the "heightForRowAtIndexPath" method of a UITableViewController, given that:

1. I'm using a custom subclassed UITableViewCell & the actually size of the subview (e.g. UILabels) is calculated at runtime & dependant on things such as if the user changed the font size
2. the cell's aren't actually prepared it seems prior to a "heightForRowAtIndexPath", so  you can't rely on calling your specific custom cell instant to query it

Only thing I can think of for the moment is to:
 1. In your custom UITableViewCell subclass create a method that calculates the heights of each subview (e.g. UILabel) that is in the UITableViewCell subclass - then use this within the cell subclass when it is creating instances
 2. Also in the custom subclass create a class method that runs through all the UILabels, calling the above-mentioned method, to sum up the heights and therefore work out the total row height.  It would have to get the data passed to it (e.g. text in each of the UILabels)
 3. In the UITableViewController "heightForRowAtIndexPath" then you have to call the "calRowHeight" type method from (2) above, passing it the label text data.  So effectively call a class method on your custom cell subclass which knows how to work out the total row height, but it's using the same logic that the cell needs too...

Is there an easier way than this I'm missing?

Comment: I've done this by introducing a class method on my custom UITableViewCell subclass, as you've mentioned.  It works, but I also question the efficiency.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a UITableView is created and whenever you send it a reloadData message, the datasource is sent one heightForRowAtIndexPath message for each cell. So if your table has 30 cells, that message gets sent 30 times.

Say only six of those 30 cells are visible on screen. In that case, when created and when you send it a reloadData message, the UITableView will send one cellForRowAtIndexPath message per visible row, i.e. that message gets sent six times.

Why do Apple implement it like this? Part of the reason is that it's almost always cheaper to calculate the height of a row than it is to build and populate a whole cell. And given that in many tables the height of every cell will be identical, it is often vastly cheaper. And part of the reason is because iOS needs to know the size of the whole table: this allows it to create the scroll bars and set it up on a scroll view etc.

If your row heights vary in size because they hold varying amounts of text, you can use one of the sizeWithFont: methods on the relevant string to do the calculations. This is quicker than building a view and then measuring the result. Note, that if you change the height of a cell, you will need to either reload the whole table (with reloadData - this will ask the delegate for every height, but only ask for visible cells) OR selectively reload the rows where the size has changed.

**Additional material**
If I understand the follow up question in the comment, the following may help:

If you are implementing an editing mode, then it's not uncommon to need to change the height of your table rows. For example, you may have text in your table rows and when they cells become narrower - to make space for the delete circles on the right - you may want some of the cells to become taller to accommodate the text. The basic approach here is to:

- Make sure the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method knows whether your are in editing mode or not. (It can ask the tableView using isEditing.) And then get the method to return the right height, depending on whether you are in editing mode or not.
- In your setEditing:animated: method in the UITableViewController (or a UIViewController, whichever you are using - there are some differences depending what you use, so it's worth checking the documentation carefully) send a reloadData message to the tableView after you have changed its state. This will force the tableView to grab the heights of every row and it will refetch the cells for the visible rows. The tableView handles making cells narrower when you enter editing mode, but if you want to do more work on the layout, do it in tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:. As noted above, the general strategy is to find a means of calculating the height that is quick. With text sizeWithFont: (and its variants) can do it. If you have images etc., then you can grab their dimensions and do some sums.
- In addition to those steps you may also want to scroll the tableView a bit after switching modes. If the heights of your rows are different, then you will end up in the wrong position in the table after switching mode. An approach I have taken here is to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay after I've reloaded the table to call a method that does the scroll adjusting. You need to use the delay, to allow time for the tableView to collect the new heights and the new table cells. (There may be a smarter way of doing this.) I do some sums to make the scroll adjustment based on the difference between the origin.y of the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the cell first visible row on screen before and after the reload. So, for e.g., to get the position before the pre-load, something a bit like this.

  ```
  CGPoint offset = [[self tableView] contentOffset];
  NSIndexPath* indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,offset.y)];
  CGFloat preCellOffset = [[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] origin].y;
  ```

Comment: thanks - re your last sentence, for the scenario where the tableview goes into/out of EDIT MODE, I was assuming I'd use the "layoutViews" method - I haven't tried to see if there's a way from within this method to set the row height for the custom tableviewcell or not?

Comment: thanks for the excellent update - interestingly I have taken LavaSlider's suggestion and within heightForRowAtIndexPath I (a) generate a temp cell using cellForRowAtIndexPath, then (b) call layoutSubviews so the subviews get set.  Then I was going to take the resultant cell view size but this doesn't seem to work  :(   I raised a question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304301/does-a-uitableviewcell-contentview-frame-size-increase-automatically-after-adding

Comment: The approach I'm recommending is what you describe in your other question as "manually look at all the subviews (e.g. UILabels) and manually determine what the overall height will be". I don't know how complex your cells are, but in my experience doing the manual calculations is fairly straightforward. It's definitely the most efficient (faster and uses less memory).  -- Anyway, good luck in getting a working solution. I've found liberal logging in the tableView delegate / datasource methods has helped me get my head around what gets called when and what depends on what etc.

Answer (score 3):

What I have done in the past, which I am not sure is the most efficient, is from within my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then I ask the view for that cell its height. I have done similar things for header and footer heights. This way if I change the cell, the header, or the footer, I don't have to remember to go and update the corresponding height method.

Comment: thats interesting - would be interesting to hear if anyone else supports this or can confirm it's not an efficient approach.  I'm trying to remember if heightForRowAtIndexPath gets called for only the limited number of cells that are going to be displayed as opposed to all cells?  (hopefully it would be the former)

Comment: It only gets called for the cells visible or partially visible on the screen. Put an NSLog() in both `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` that report the row and section then watch when they are called.

Comment: was going to hold off marking this as the answer until I check whether the resultant temp cell generated by cellForRowAtIndexPath can be readily used to get the overall height or not...i.e. refer to issue I have here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304301/does-a-uitableviewcell-contentview-frame-size-increase-automatically-after-adding