# does a UITableViewCell contentView frame size increase automatically after adding subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

does a UITableViewCell contentView frame size increase automatically after adding subviews?

Suppose that you:

- add a few subview (e.g. UILabel's) to the UITableViewCell content view
- then set the UILabel size/position using the label.frame = CGRectMake(... approach
- then is the UITableViewCell's frame size change automatically to accommodate this - i.e. if you go tableViewCell.contentView.frame.size.height should this be the total height required to just fit in the subviews?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so... That doesn't seem logical really. You set the frame height for your cells via UITableView property rowHeight or by implementing UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: interestly it is within heightForRowAtIndexPath that I'm trying to determine the height that the row will be. So the approach suggested was to create a temporary cell via using cellForRowAtIndexPath and then measure it's dimensions.  However the issue here is the overall dimensions of the UITableViewCell doesn't seem to reflect/adjust to the subview within it then?  So this would imply I would have to manually look at all the subviews (e.g. UILabels) and manually determine what the overall height will be?

Comment: Hi! heightForRowAtIndexPath is actually called before cellForRowAtIndexPath, so I suggest that you precalculate all your row heights and store them as a property inside objects you are trying to describe with table cells. Then use these values when heightForRowAtIndexPath asks how high should a row for a particular cell be.