# How to set row Height on a tableView that is dynamically populated? (Titanium Studio)

Tags: iphone, titanium

I am new to Titanium Studio. Need to set row height dynamically but, I unable to set dynamic height in each row. Below is my code:

**textArray contains 10 text paragraphs. each paragraph have different height.**

```
var myTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({height:360, width: 306, top: 58, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',borderColor: '#C8C8C8',borderWidth:2, zIndex: -1});
var myArray = [];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({contentHeight: 'auto', width: 320,top:0});

    var my = Ti.UI.createView({ top:10,width:300,height:'auto' });

    var myText = Ti.UI.createlLabel({text:textArray[i],width:50,height:'auto',left:10,top:5,borderRadius:4});

    my.add(myText);

    row.add(my);
    myArray.push(row);

}
```

How can i set row height dynamically.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
specify your table rowHeight as auto.

var myTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({height:400,rowHeight: 'auto', width: 312, top: 10,left:4, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',borderColor: '#C8C8C8',borderWidth:2, zIndex: -1});
var myArray=[];   

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //create row in table.
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height: 'auto', width: 310,top:10, selectionStyle : Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE});

    //textArray contains 10 elements. i am using this in each loop..
    var myText = Ti.UI.createlLabel({text:textArray[i],width:50,height:50,left:10,top:5,borderRadius:4});

    //add like this what ever you want...
    row.add(myText);

    myArray.push(row);

}

//store in table
myTable.data = myArray;

//disply table.
win.add(myTable);
```

**If height:'auto' property is not working then use Ti.UI.SIZE**

I hope.. someone will use it.

Answer (score 1):

As per understanding you need to show cell height as per text

Here are some good example

1. [Similar post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128215/ios-dynamic-height-with-a-custom-uitableviewcell)
2. [Example given on some blog](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/)

Hope this will solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks..I am working in Titanium Studio Mobile Development. my code is different from this answer specified code.

Answer (score -1):

Change the content height to what you want table height look